# How I can improve the style of this title?

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec

I'm working on book class and happen to have a relatively long title, when I write I get this:
[image]

I would go up a bit the title, but that short titles remain in place

[image]

[image]
but that short titles remain in place, thanks in advance :)

[image]

The important thing of the code is here:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[total={5.2in,9.73in},top=1in, left=1.2in,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\RequirePackage{fourier}         % Fuente palatino
\RequirePackage{pstricks}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{12pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\huge\bfseries}{{
   \fontsize{4.1em}{4.1em}\selectfont\black
   \thechapter}\hsp\textcolor{cyan}{\vrule height 2.7em width 1pt}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
\begin{document}
     \setcounter{chapter}{12}
 \chapter{Leyes generales de conservación y simetrías}\lipsum[1-4]
      \setcounter{chapter}{16}
 \chapter{Teoría de Hamilton-Jacobi}\lipsum[1-4]
   \end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, it would be more convenient for helpers if you would provide the *important code* inside a minimal working example. Makes testing possible solutions much easier.

Comment: @Johannes_B Okay, :D

Comment: You should not allow hyphenation in titles

Comment: @Bernard I know, thanks, It was for example.. :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can align on the bottom row of the title:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{color,lmodern,titlesec}
\newcommand\chptitle[1]{\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-87pt}{\raggedright#1}}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{12pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\huge\bfseries}{{
    \fontsize{4.1em}{4.1em}\selectfont\color{black}%
    \thechapter}\hsp\textcolor{blue}{\vrule height 2.7em width 1pt}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries\chptitle}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Aaaa bbbb}

aa

\chapter{Aaaa bbbb Aaaa bbbb Aaaa bbbb}

bb

\end{document}
```